# How to export function return value into data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm new to writing functions in R, so I'm still trying to figure out some basics. The values that are returned by the function are correct, but I can't figure out how to export these values into a dataframe. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

See below the code:

```
create.f <- function(x=1000,s=0.7) {
  return(function() {
    x <<- x * s
    print(x)
  })
  }
f <- create.f()
for (i in 1:5) f()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?replicate` :

```
f <- create.f()
DF <- data.frame(values = replicate(5, f()))
```

giving:

```
> DF
  values
1 700.00
2 490.00
3 343.00
4 240.10
5 168.07
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this!